# How to recover formatted drive encrypted with bitlocker?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, google-chrome, encryption, data-recovery

I was using Windows 10. For some reason, I tried to install Ubuntu but it deleted my all data.
I have recovered some data. But I could not get my data from the drive which was encrypted with bitlocker. Then I reinstalled Windows 10, and that drive is appearing empty.
I have used different softwares for data recovery but nothing helped. What should I do?

Comment: You would need your bitlocker recovery disk and a good data recovery company.

Comment: Actually, in theory, it's possible... but not with regular recovery software. Becasue, Bitlocker encrypts file-system, and that's exactly what a recovery software looks for to find volumes... "Intact File-System!"If the data in drive is intact, and you can dump it sector-by-sector to another partition or VHD file, there's a chance you have a brand new Bitlocker enabled volume to unlock!

Comment: A skilled forensic-investigator with a good understanding of files system is recommended to achieve this goal. (but not 100% possible)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think even the CIA would be able to get your data back at this point.
My guess is that at some point, either during your Ubuntu or your Windows installation, you have formatted the partition containing your Bitlocker data. If this would have been a non-encrypted partition, you would have had a chance of recovering some files. Yet because you would need the entire, untouched Bilocker-protected partition in order to restore it (you don't), you won't be seeing you data back.

Take away lessons:

- When doing experiments like this, don't use your day-to-day computer, but use a test machine.
- If you *have* to use your own machine, first make backups. Actually... always make backups. Every day, or soms system that auto-backups any files changed.

So, unfortunately, the answer to this question is... "You can't"

Comment: Another excuse for me to trot out the adage... "Any data not stored in at least three distinct locations ought to be considered temporary."

Comment: To be honest, I'm sure each of us faced similar data-loss before turning that knowledge into practice. It's almost like a rite-of-passage :)

Comment: I think I started making backups, to MO & DAT, back in the 90s. Before that I just got lucky & never lost anything significant. These days, one in-house [hourly] & one offsite [daily] for all the important machines. As a rite of passage, I'm very glad I never had to find out the hard way ;)